# How to Use Unix Bash scripts or awk scripts as Hive UDF using Transform?

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hive

I Was Trying to run one Hive query Using "TRANSFORM", PFB the sample query

For e.g :-

```
SELECT TRANSFORM (*)
  USING 'worker.py' as (sum)
  FROM mysource_filetable
```

In the above example Python is used for UDF for calaculation of sum of all columns.

I don't want to use either Python or Java Code as UDF, is it a way we can use Bash script to take the sum of all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the Hive streaming UDF functionality can be used with any script type. Just specify the executable and the script (after the resource has been added). So for this example your code would look something like like this:

```
SELECT TRANSFORM (*)
  USING 'sh worker.sh' as (sum)
  FROM mysource_filetable
```

Make sure you are following the other guidelines for streaming UDFs, e.g. you are reading from stdin and passing values through stdout. You can find out more here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Transform